# Submit through a Partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Partial View as a Table, that will be refreshed with a Dropdown Selection in the Main View. This dropdown list includes company names. In the table below information matters pertaining to each company, and for each line of this information there is a drop-down list of all the functions that I can do with this line (like deleting or modifying the information) with a Pop-up Modal.

How can I call a Method in the main Model or Submit something? Or can I create a Partial View with Model in my Case?

Here is my Main View:

```
@page
@model Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Pages.Information_listModel
@{
}

<form>
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Wählen Sie eine Unternehmen aus</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.companies.Count; i++)
                {
                    <option>@Model.companies[i].FirmenKurzBezeichnung</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" style="margin-top: 31px;" placeholder="Suche...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 31px;">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="fachinfoContainer">
    <partial name="_FachinfoPartial" model="@Model.myViewModel" />
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#inputState").change(function () {
                var selectcompany = "";
                if ($(this).val() != "Wählen Sie die Firma aus...") {
                    selectcompany = $(this).val();
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Actions/Information-List?handler=fachinfoPartial",
                    type: "Get",
                    data: { company: selectcompany },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#fachinfoContainer").html(""); //clear the fachinfo container.
                        $("#fachinfoContainer").html(result); //populate the container.
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here is my Partial View

```
@model Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Models.MyViewModel
<table class="table table-striped" id="FachinfoTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Letzte Änderung</th>
            <th scope="col">Aktuelle Version</th>
            <th scope="col">Auftrag</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
        @if (@Model.Fachinfos != null)
        {
            @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Fachinfos.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@Model.Fachinfos[i].FachinfoNummer</th>
                    <td>@Model.Fachinfos[i].FachinfoName</td>
                    <td>@Model.Fachinfos[i].Status</td>
                    <td>@Model.Fachinfos[i].Datum</td>
                    <td>@Model.Fachinfos[i].PdfVersion</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                @for (int c = 0; c < @Model.SelectedCompany.Permissions.Count; c++)
                                {
                                    if (Model.SelectedCompany.Permissions[c] != Models.Company.Permission.ERSTERFASSEN && Model.SelectedCompany.Permissions[c] != Models.Company.Permission.ABFRAGEN)
                                    {
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-number="@Model.Fachinfos[i].FachinfoNummer" data-version="@Model.Fachinfos[i].PdfVersion" data-target="#@Model.SelectedCompany.Permissions[c]">@Model.SelectedCompany.Permissions[c]</a>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- The Delete Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="@Models.Company.Permission.LOESCHEN">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Bestätigen</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span id="deletMessege">Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie diese Fachinformation löschen möchten?</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="confirm" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Senden</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

 $('#@Models.Company.Permission.LOESCHEN').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var fiNumber = button.data('number') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Fachinfonummer ' + fiNumber)
    })
</script>
```

Here is my main model

```
using Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Classes;
using Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Pages
{
    public class Information_listModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Company> companies { get; set; }
        public List<Fachinfo> fachinfos = new List<Fachinfo>();
        public MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            companies = APIRequester.GetCompanies(User.Identity.Name);
            foreach (var company in companies)
            {
                fachinfos.AddRange(APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company.FirmenKurzBezeichnung));
            }
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetFachinfoPartial(string company)
        {
            //based on the selctedcompany to filter data, then return to the partial view.
            companies = APIRequester.GetCompanies(User.Identity.Name);
            myViewModel = new MyViewModel()
            {
                SelectedCompany = companies.Find(r => r.FirmenKurzBezeichnung == company),  //get the company object here
                Fachinfos = APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company)
            };

            return Partial("_FachinfoPartial", myViewModel);
        }
        
        //Submit this Method from Partial view
        public IActionResult onDelete(string fiNumber)
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. A view is not something you throw. Do you mean "Submit through a Partial view"?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, sorry english is not the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY AJAX calls for this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Information_listModel?handler=Ondelete', 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data.result);
})
```

your method should return type `IActionResult`

Comment: That didn't work, I have Razore Page Project. Did you mean so? `<a asp-action="onDelete" asp-controller="Information_listModel">Submit to Main Controller</a>`

Comment: How can I use URL in Ajax to call the main model, can you write an example for me please!

Comment: I thought you were using MVC. see my edited answer